# ID<>SQL statement doesn't work when SQL statement returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two data tables, one called `EmployeeDetails` with the columns `Name` and `ID`, and one called `EmployeeProject` with columns `ProjectID` and `EmployeeID`.

Now I want to get all employees which are not linked to the project. I tried to write it as a stored procedure, with a parameter `@ProjectID`, to define for which project I want to know, what employees are not assigned.

I tried it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Temp.ID), 
    Temp.AssignedDevelopers 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         ED.ID, ED.Name As AssignedDevelopers, P.ProjectID 
     FROM 
         EmployeeDetails ED 
     LEFT JOIN 
         EmployeeProject P on ED.ID = P.EmployeeID) Temp
WHERE 
    ID <> (SELECT EmployeeID 
           FROM EmployeeProject 
           WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectID AND EmployeeID = Temp.ID)
```

The problem is when no one is assigned to the project I don't get a result.

Comment: What result are you expecting if no one is assigned to the project?  Isn't no result telling you that no one is assigned?

Comment: No, if no one is assigned, I want to get all employees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using NOT IN instead of <>

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Temp.ID), Temp.AssignedDevelopers FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ED.ID, ED.Name As AssignedDevelopers, P.ProjectID FROM EmployeeDetails ED  LEFT JOIN EmployeeProject P on ED.ID=P.EmployeeID) Temp WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT EmployeeID FROM EmployeeProject WHERE ProjectID=@ProjectID AND EmployeeID=Temp.ID)
```